# SharePoint Online, "Latest Activity" webpart in Classic Mode?

Tags: classic-experience, activity-feed

Is there something like [Site Activity](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-site-activity-web-part-1fa91401-ac36-42b6-beba-bb8469d6cbfa) in Classic Mode? Want to show latest activities on welcome page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content search web part or the content query web part

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a

https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Publishing-Infrastructure-Content-Query.htm

Comment: Thank You @susan! Tried to get activities programmatically (used GetChanges REST Api, but there was nothing interesting, only internal information with Guids and timestamps..) If there is no other way, I'll mark Yours as answer!